# Rails 5 - Onmi Auth Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Im working on an App, I  would not like the user to register with facebook, but once the account is created I would like the user to have the option to connect to facebook to be able to grab their profile picture and some basic info if permitted.

Will omni-auth be my best option to do this? or is there a better tool out there? I've never used omni auth or created anything like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use gem 'omniauth-facebook' and devise to achive this . once the user is created save the access_token in table and then using facebook graph api and token you will get profile pic and basic info

Comment: fantastic! thanks very much!